# How to return a "C" value by search in an "B" array with "A" id

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I don't understand how i can search in an array with a value and return another value from the searched row.

So, I used foreach/for loops for this but it returns me only for the first function request. After 1 use, the function returns null value.

**Here is the code for the for loop:**

```
$users = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM userkeys');
$scripts = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM scripts');

function GetNameFromId($users, $id){ // $users = PDO Statement - $id = value to search in array
  $users = $users->fetchAll(); 
  for($i = 0, $size = count($users); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    if($users[$i]['id'] == $id){
      return $users[$i]['name'];
      
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is the code for the foreach loop:**

```
$users = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM userkeys');
$scripts = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM scripts');

function GetNameFromId($users, $id) { // $users = PDO Statement - $id = value to search in array
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if($user['id'] == $id) {
            return $user['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

**Where the code is executed ?**
The problem is where i call the function :
*echo GetNameFromId($users, [...]) . '<br>';*

```
<tbody>
                    <?php foreach($scripts as $script): ?>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <?= $script['id']; ?>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <?= $script['name']; ?>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <?= $script['price']; ?>
                      </th>
                      <td>
                        <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
                          
                          <?php if($script['state'] == 1){?>
                            <i class="bg-danger"></i>
                            <span class="status">démarrage</span>
                          <?php }elseif($script['state'] == 2){ ?>
                            <i class="bg-info"></i>
                            <span class="status">en cours</span>
                          <?php }elseif($script['state'] == 3){ ?>
                            <i class="bg-warning"></i>
                            <span class="status">en retard</span>
                          <?php }elseif($script['state'] == 4){ ?>
                            <i class="bg-success"></i>
                            <span class="status">livré</span>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                          <span class="completion mr-2"><?= $script['percent']; ?>%</span>
                          <div>
                            <div class="progress">
                              <?php if($script['percent'] <= 33){?>
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $script['percent']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?= $script['percent']; ?>%;"></div>
                              <?php }elseif($script['percent'] > 33 AND !($script['percent'] == 100)){ ?>
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $script['percent']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?= $script['percent']; ?>%;"></div>
                              <?php }else{ ?>
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $script['percent']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?= $script['percent']; ?>%;"></div>
                              <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <?php 
                            $decode = json_decode($script['client_id']);
                            echo var_dump($decode);
                            if(is_array($decode)){
                              for($i = 0, $size = count($decode); $i < $size; ++$i) {
                                echo GetNameFromId($users, intval($decode[$i])) . '<br>'; 
                              }
                              
                            }else{
                              echo GetNameFromId($users, $script['client_id']) . '<br>';
                            }
                          ?>
                      </th>
                      <td>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-pen text-info"></i>
                          </a>
                          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="updates.php?type=1&id=<?= $script['idhash']; ?>">Ajouter une update</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="updates.php?type=2&id=<?= $script['idhash']; ?>">Modifier le script</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="updates.php?type=3&id=<?= $script['idhash']; ?>">Supprimer le script</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </tbody>
```

**To resume, when i use the function 1 times, it works perfectly but if i use it more than 1 times, the first value is ok but all other are null.**

Thank's !

Comment: If you want to select 1 user, are you using SQL of something like `SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE id = ?`?

Comment: I think it will make many and many SQL request. So i don't think it's a good idea ? I get all the users before and then i want to check. In fact, i want to do this with a <table> and list all of the users.

Answer (score 0):

I read this correctly when you do this

```
$users = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM userkeys');
```

you are actually returning a statement object, not an array.
You can't reuse the statement object over and over, you should fetch all the rows from the object and place that in the $users array. From that point forward you can reuse the $users variable as an array.

Here is my example

```
$usersstmt = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM userkeys');
$users = $usersstmt->fetchAll();
$scriptsstmt = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM scripts');
$scripts= $scriptsstmt->fetchAll();



function GetNameFromId($users, $id){
   foreach($users as $user) {
      if($user['id'] == $id){
         return $user['name'];
      }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply, i've edited the original message to add all the code.